# Set what datatable will show to the GridView1 because i'm using sqlCommand LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

here's my SqlCommand

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT a.*,b.ID,b.Firstname,b.Middlename,
    b.Lastname,b.Friendswith,b.Amount  from [User_TBL_DB] a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Friends_TBL_DB] b ON a.ID=b.Friendswith", conn);
```

basically i call 2 `datatable` and compare them. So no problem with that 
now I want to show my data using `GridView` but what I want is to select `[User_TBL_DB]` only and not the `[Friends_TBL_DB]`
Table database.

example:

after I set the `SqlCommand`I will set the

`SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);`

in here it will select both `[User_TBL_DB]` and `[Friends_TBL_DB]` then I will set

```
da.Fill(ds);
```

and the next thing that I will do is to call it to the `GridView`

```
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

Where will I filter the data ? Is it posible to call one `datatable` using that `SqlCommand`? Because I don't want to call it one more time. I want to open my sqlcommand once.

this is the current output of it ^_^

[image]

i tried to use the group by but it's not working

Comment: Is this query used some where else other than binding GridView?

Comment: Have you considered `stored procedure`  ?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? You are going to get the common records form the both tables + all records of the left table by join query and when you bind that data table to gridview all the data will be visible on grid .

Comment: Are you using "AutoGeneratedColumns = true" for your gridview ?

Comment: I added a picture on my post

Answer (score 1):

If the query is only used for binding `GridView`, do not select the `[Friends_TBL_DB]` table's column. Try something like,

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT a.* from [User_TBL_DB] a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Friends_TBL_DB] b ON a.ID = b.Friendswith", conn);
```

Comment: i can't use this coz i need to select all the fields because i will call this command twice .. i'm using parent and child gridview too.. the concept is to  view the [User_TBL_DB] to GridView1 and view the [Friends_TBL_DB] to GridView2 which is the child GridView (Nested GridView)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try something like this

```
   Create procedure dbo.GetSomething
   as
   begin
        SELECT a.*,b.ID,b.Firstname,b.Middlename,
b.Lastname,b.Friendswith,b.Amount  from [User_TBL_DB] a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Friends_TBL_DB] b ON a.ID=b.Friendswith;

  select * from [User_TBL_DB];

  end;


   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetSomething", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

You will get two dataset.You can assign your second table as your datasource to gridview.

Comment: wait if i will do this my another gridview will have the same output and to change it i need to create another stored procedure

Comment: i need to select all the fields because i will call this command twice .. i'm using parent and child gridview too.. the concept is to view the [User_TBL_DB] to GridView1 and view the [Friends_TBL_DB] to GridView2 which is the child GridView (Nested GridView)

Comment: you sound confused.What you wanted to acheive(from this question) was to get two tables in the dataset which you have it.If you have any other problems post a new question.

Comment: what im thinking is.. if there is a way where i call use my SqlCommand (that one) and be able to control what will show in my Gridview .. look at my question again I added a screenshot ^_^

Comment: anyway i appreciated your effort and I will try this ^_^ thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm a litle confuse. When you do LEFT OUTER JOIN you aren't comparing them, you are combining them in a cartesian product where a.ID=b.Friendswith and also all the rows in the table [User_TBL_DB] who ID doesn't have a value equal in b.FriendsWith So, if you put "SELECT a.*" you get exactly the same result that select the table [User_TBL_DB] without the LEFT OUTER JOIN

Ok, I got it.

Wath you need to do is add your rows in a for each loop and verify the data of [User_TBL_DB] you are trying to add is not repeat, then use a nested foreach loop to fill a second GridView with the fields from [Friends_TBL_DB] and adding all this to the main GridView like this:

```
...
da.Fill(ds); 
foreach(DataRow r in ds[0].Rows)
{
    List<DataRow> l = (from DataRow row in GridView1 where row.Item["Id"] == r.Item["Id"]).toList();
    if(l==0)
    {
        GridView GridView2 = new GridView();
        foreach(DataRow r2 in ds[0])
            if(r.Item["Id"]==r2.Item["Id"])
                GridView2.Rows.Add(r2.Item["bFirstName"], r2.Item["etc..."]);
        GridView1.Rows.Add(r.Item["Id"], r.Item["etc..."], GridView2);
    }
}
```

Comment: my bad .. you're right i'm combining them ^_^ so that's the purpose of it then i use if condition to filter the next GridView (Nested GridView) the concept is to view the [User_TBL_DB] to GridView1 and view The [Friends_TBL_DB] to GridView to which is the child Gridview while combining them i will be able to determine who will be the friend of the user using their IDs ..  if id on User_TBL_DB is equal to friendwith(this the id of the user ) on [Friends_TBL_DB] the row will be visible and if not, it will hide ^_^

Comment: Ok..., I'm much more confuse now. Are you saying you have 2 GridView and you want to fill them with one DataTable?

Comment: 2 datatables but yes ...remember i select both of them on my sqlCommand? all i have to do now is to control what will comeout on my gridview

Comment: I added screenshot please look

Comment: Nope, if you do only one SELECT you get only one DataTable.

Comment: yes but in one select i'm able to get both data of my two Database which is the [User_TBL_TB] and [Friends_TBL_DB] so i called them both using different id's i just discovered that if you join 2 database in one gridview it will generate another id from the original one like 
[User_TBL_TB] firstname, middlename, lastname
[Friends_TBL_DB]  firstname, middlename, lastname
the same right? but after you call it to the Gridview the ID of the second database will become 
[Friends_TBL_DB]  firstname1, middlename1, lastname1
so yeah ^_^ does it make any sense? im sorry i'm so zombie today haha

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. If you have a nested GridView you need a nested loop to fill it.